# How to use to check if a coordinate is within a certain distance from one of many specific places?

Tags: ios, objective-c, location

I'll have a coordinate, and I will need to, for example, check if it is within half a mile from any Macy's store or Walmart store. Is there a way to do this without storing the coordinate of the each and every walmart/macy's store, but just use the keywords of "walmart" or "macys"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`MKLocalSearch`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKLocalSearch/Reference/Reference.html). Note, if you're going to search for both Macy's and Walmart's, you will do two searches with two different search objects because, as the documentation says:

> An `MKLocalSearch` object initiates a map-based search operation and delivers the results back to your app asynchronously. Search objects are designed to perform one search operation only. To perform several different searches, you must create separate instances of this class and start them separately.

Anyway, the basic code looks something like:

```
// create new search request

MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"Walmart";
request.region = mapView.region; // or create your `region` manually if not using a map

// initiate new search

MKLocalSearch *localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
   for (MKMapItem *item in response.mapItems) {

        // do whatever you want with the results
    }];
}];
```